# Return sub-document from nested list based on multiple match criteria

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Hi I have the following document, I want to extract message from messagelist based on multiple criteria.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("58df770371043e7087cdaadd"),
"prospectemailid" : "abc@gmail.com",
"prospectid" : "1491038545032",
"useremail" : "xyz@gmail.com",
"threadidslist" : [ 
    {
        "threadid" : "15b28e8e711f71b0",
        "subject" : "sub",
        "campaignid" : "1491460056589",
        "messagelist" : [ 
            {
                "emailuniqueid" : "1492376430400",
                "messageid" : "15b28e8e711f71b0",
                "timestamp" : "Sat Apr 01 15:16:43 IST 2017",
                "from" : "utsavanand.work@gmail.com",
                "body" : "Hello",
                "labelid" : "SENT",
                "to" : "anuragkv10@gmail.com",
                "messageidpayload" : ""
            }, 
            {
                "emailuniqueid" : "1492376430400",
                "messageid" : "15b28ecbcbe5b32d",
                "timestamp" : "Sat Apr 01 15:20:54 IST 2017",
                "from" : "anuragkv10@gmail.com",
                "body" : "Hi",
                "labelid" : "RECEIVED",
                "to" : "utsavanand.work@gmail.com",
                "messageidpayload" : "<CAL_CU77Rc27peuGde=WTC7waW3gfvS2Wr_t2A+7KBjjxsKW8Sw@mail.gmail.com>"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Expected output based on 
Criteria : prospectemailid=1491038545032,useremail=xyz@gmail.com,threadidslist.campaignid=1491460056589 and messagelist.emailuniqueid= 1492376430400 is

```
{
               "emailuniqueid" : "1492376430400",
                "messageid" : "15b28ecbcbe5b32d",
                "timestamp" : "Sat Apr 01 15:20:54 IST 2017",
                "from" : "sad@gmail.com",
                "body" : "Hi",
                "labelid" : "RECEIVED",
                "to" : asd@gmail.com",
                "messageidpayload" : "<CAL_CU77Rc27peuGde=WTC7waW3gfvS2Wr_t2A+7KBjjxsKW8Sw@mail.gmail.com>"
 }
```

Thanks..!

So far i have tried:

```
db.getCollection('GD').aggregate(
[

   { $match:{
        "prospectid" : "1491038545032",
        "useremail" : "xyz@gmail.com",
        "threadidslist.campaignid" : "1491460056589",
        "threadidslist.messagelist.emailuniqueid" : "1492376430400"
    }

}   
])
```

Comment: @chridam Mongo Version : 3.4 ,I have included what i have tried so far in ques.

Answer (score 2):

Use the **[`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/#exp._S_arrayElemAt)** and **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter)** operators in a **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline to get the filtered nested array. The **[`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/#pipe._S_replaceRoot)** pipeline will promote the filtered subdocument to the top level and replaces all other fields.

Consider running the following pipeline to get the desired result:

```
db.GD.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "prospectid" : "1491038545032",
        "useremail" : "xyz@gmail.com",
        "threadidslist.campaignid" : "1491460056589",
        "threadidslist.messagelist.emailuniqueid" : "1492376430400"
    } }, 
    { "$project": { 
        "threadidslist": {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
                { 
                    "$filter": {
                        "input": "$threadidslist",
                        "as": "thread",
                        "cond": { "$eq": ["$$thread.campaignid", "1491460056589"] }
                    }                
                },
                0
            ]
        }
    } },
    { "$project": { 
        "messagelist": {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
                { 
                    "$filter": {
                        "input": "$threadidslist.messagelist",
                        "as": "msg",
                        "cond": { "$eq": ["$$msg.emailuniqueid", "1492376430400"] }
                    }                
                },
                0
            ]
        }
    } },
    { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$messagelist" } }
])
```

Comment: It gives me error unrecognized pipe line stage $replaceroot, but after removing { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$messagelist" } }. It works like charm.  Thanks a lot ... :)